# solving integral if you know support for whole function

Tags: integration

I have a function $\\f(x,y) = x*y\\$

I would like to solve an integral $\\\int f(x,y)\ dxdy$

But I have this funky support:

$\\\begin{Bmatrix}-\infty < x<\infty\\\ -\infty < y<\infty\\ 0<f(x,y)<10\end{Bmatrix}$

My question is how to solve this kind of integrals if it is possible of course? Are there any definitions?

Comment: Does "solve" mean "evaluate"? What is your function $f$, specifically? Without that, there is nothing to do

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that, I edited it

Comment: Do you think you are supposed to integrate only over the region where $0<f<10$? If so, then that would be the regions in the first and third quadrants bounded by the axes and the hyperbola $xy=10$.

Comment: Basically yes, but i do not know how to solve it.

Comment: @MPW But how to solve this integral where you have support by function, not the parameters of the function... what would be the end result of this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to parameterize the region $D$ where $0<f<10$. This is exactly the region between the hyperbola $xy=10$ and the axes. Both $x$ and $y$ can take on any value, but for a given value of (say) $y$, you know that $x$ can only vary between the axis and the hyperbola--that is, between $10/y$ and $0$ when $y$ is negative, and between $0$ and $10/y$ when $y$ is positive. Drawing the region always helps!

So your integral will be $$\int_D f(x,y)\;dx\;dy = \int_{y=-\infty}^0\left(\int_{x=10/y}^{x=0}xy\; dx\right)dy + \int_{y=0}^{y=\infty}\left(\int_{x=0}^{x=10/y} xy\;dx\right)\;dy$$

Now you can try to evaluate this integral.

Hmm, I think this diverges.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes you are correct, it diverges, since first term is infinity and infinity + N = infinity. So we can as well say, this function can not be a pdf, since multiplying with constant C = 0 would result in 0. Would my thinking be right?